# Github Actions OIDC - what are all the possible values of the "sub" claim on the token (for creating trust policy)

Tags: amazon-web-services, git, github-actions, openid-connect

After some permissions errors with the `aws-actions/amazon-ecr-login`, I finally realized - after stumbling upon [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75890374/github-action-failing-on-error-not-authorized-to-perform-stsassumerolewithwebi) - that I had configured the sub claim in the AWS Trust Policy wrong. I had blindly copied from the github docs which used `repo:<ghub-user><repo>:ref/refs/head` or whatever (I forget... they've since updated [the docs](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/deployment/security-hardening-your-deployments/configuring-openid-connect-in-amazon-web-services) to a sensible but permissive default)...

It got me thinking, **what is the list of possible values for the `sub` claim** then, when selecting the repo actions the oidc will be used for?

I think the most common use cases would be credentials for:

- any action on a branch named X
- any action on any branch tagged X
- any PUSH to a branch named X
- any PUSH anywhere in the repo
- any PR anywhere in the repo
- any action on any PR
- any action on a PR targeting branch X

This [AWS page](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/access-analyzer-reference-policy-checks.html#access-analyzer-reference-policy-checks-general-warning-specific-github-repo-and-branch-recommended) suggests restrictions such as the above are better than "*" wildcard, and I didn't see these discussed on the github oidc page.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This page lists the subject claims:

https://docs.github.com/en/actions/deployment/security-hardening-your-deployments/about-security-hardening-with-openid-connect#example-subject-claims

- environment: repo:<orgName/repoName>:environment:
- branch: repo:<orgName/repoName>:ref:refs/heads/branchName
- tag: repo:<orgName/repoName>:ref:refs/tags/
- pull requests: repo:<orgName/repoName>:pull_request